# Can We Use "Message" as an (custom) Event to Fire a Tag in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have an `id` being pushed to my data layer via `dataLayer.push()` and there is no event key at the moment.

I know the best practice is to use an event key like `'event': 'idPush'` and then in Google Tag Manager UI, have a trigger that activates when the custom event `idPush` occurs.

Is there is a way that I can still get the trigger to activate upon seeing a generic `'Message'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure because I haven't read the GTM source code and I couldn't find any articles that talk about this, but I'm reasonably certain that this can't be done.

I tried:

- creating a `Custom Event` trigger with a regex match of `.*` which would match anything, including nothing.
- matching `undefined`, because according to the preview pane, the `_event` variable is set to `undefined` for `Message` events.

Unfortunately neither of these worked, and preview mode just says `No tags were evaluated` for the `Message`.  This leads me to think that GTM only checks to see if any triggers should fire when an `event` is pushed into the `dataLayer`.

Comment: As you probably know you can inject javascript onto the page when the page loads using GTM, so maybe you could use that in some way as a workaround until you can change your pages' code again.  That might not be possible depending on how you page works, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

No. Until there was an event, GTM does not know about the content of the message - the message is just the debugger telling you that something has been added to the global dataLayer variable (which exists in the global namespace of the browser, not the confined namespace of GTM). The even is what updates GTM's internal state to make it aware of changes and additions to the dataLayer.

Depending on your use case you might be able to use a trigger type that creates it's own event - e.g. setting a visibility trigger to an element that you know will be at the viewport after your message, which will then take the new values of the dataLayer into account. Or create a custom HTML tag with a setInterval functions that periodically pushes an event to the dataLayer.

While these solutions may work, I do not think they are actually good. Finding a solution to change your page code will almost certainly be less headache in the long run than using a workaround.